# Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, where $a<b$. Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$. Prove that there exists number $c_{1},c_{2},...,c_{2012}$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ satisfying $c_{1} < c_{2} <...< c_{2012}$ and $f'(c_{1})+f'(c_{2})+...+f'(c_{2012})=0$.

I believe it has something to do with Rolle's Theorem, judging by the hypotheses. However, I can't seem to find a way to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @all: Thanks for all your kind help and guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best and most direct solution has been given by *robjohn*. Let us just construct another explicit possible proof by iteration if one does not want to use the mean value theorem of derivatives. If $f$ has continuous derivative in a neighborhood of one of its critical points, then it is almost straightforward to get such $c_1<...<c_n$ for any $n\in 2\mathbb{Z}^+$ using the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) for continuous functions. If $f'$ is not continuous in a neighborhood of the critical point, then trickier arguments are needed but I think the process explained below can give you an idea of what to explore to generalize for that case. To understand the idea take a look at the (badly done) picture:

[image]

*(**Warning**: As noticed by Landscape in the comments, this argument only works when the concavity/convexity does not change around $c_0$, i.e. the critical point is not an inflexion point)*. By Rolle's theorem let $c_0\in (a,b)$ be where $f'(c_0)=0$ and let $[c_0-d,c_0+d]\subseteq (a,b)$ be our interval of the critical point where we are assuming $f'$ is continuous. Since $f$ has at least a critical point in that interval, $c_0$, we can restrict further to a closed neighborhood of it, $[c_0-\delta,c_0+\delta]$ with $\delta>0$ but small, so that $f'$ has different sign at the extremes of the interval, that is, $f'(c_0-\delta)\cdot f'(c_0+\delta)<0$ (this is intuitively clear as any function satisfying $f(a)=f(b)$ with continuous derivative around its critical point inside that interval looks like $\frown$ or $\smile$ for a sufficiently small neighborhood). Then by the [intermediate value theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5PJj.jpg) on $f'$ in that interval, $f'$ must take all values in between $f'(c_0-\delta)$ and $f'(c_0+\delta)$. Since they are of different sign, let us suppose it is $f'(c_1)>0$ for $c_1:=c_0-\delta$, so you have an interval in the image of $f'$ given by $[f'(c_0+\delta),f'(c_0-\delta)]$ such that $$f'(c_0+\delta)<0<f'(c_0-\delta).$$ One of them is also bigger or equal in absolute value than the other, suppose it is $f'(c_0+\delta)$ (cf. picture above). Thus, by the intermediate value theorem, there must exist $c_2\in [c_1, c_0+\delta]$ such that $f'(c_1)>0>f'(c_2):=-f'(c_1)>f'(c_0+\delta)$, i.e. you get a new subinterval $[c_1,c_2]\ni c_0$ where $f'(c_2)=-f'(c_1)\Rightarrow f'(c_1)+f'(c_2)=0$. Since this new interval still satisfies the conditions of the intermediate value theorem for $f'$, you may iterate this process for smaller subintervals of it, containing $c_0$, so you can always pick new $c_{i+1}$ at the other side of $c_0$ such that $f'(c_{i+1})=-f'(c_i)$. After getting $n\in 2\mathbb{Z}^+$ of them (you need a even number so that you get pairs of points where your derivative takes opposite values so that they cancel in the sum), rename the set $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^n$ in increasing order, so that eventually $f'(c_1)+\cdots+f'(c_n)=0$, as they can always be paired up again in opposite values by construction.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you!

Comment: Hi, Javier Álvarez, sorry for bothering. I'm tidying up my posts, and then come across this one. Your statement "so that $f′$ has different sign at the extremes of the interval" is false. For example, you may consider $f(x)=x^3$ with $c_0=0$. By the way, I don't understand why you think robjohn's answer is more direct than mine. @drawar

Comment: @Landscape: hi, the argument is right because $f$ is assumed to satisfy $f(a)=f(b)$ so your example $x^3$ with $c_0=0$ is not applicable here. I think either robjohn's was the only other answer available when I posted mine or I saw his hint more straightforward for me to see immediately.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: My counter-exmaple is only to your statement that  if $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f'(c_0)=0$, then $f'(c_0-\delta)\cdot f'(c_0+\delta)<0$ for some $\delta>0$ small. Anyway, if you want $f(a)=f(b)$, then  $f(x)=x^3(1-x^2)$ with $c_0=0$, $a=-1$, $b=1$ is still a counter-example to your statement.

Comment: @Landscape: my fault, you are completely right! I have edited my answer specifying you pointed out this shortcoming of the argument, i.e. that it only works when the critical point is not an inflection point so that $f'$ changes sign around it. Thank you for the warning and excuse me for not noticing it before.

Comment: @JavierÁlvarez: You are welcome. Please never mind. Actually I should apologize for digging a so old post out.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Let $x_k=a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)$ and note that
$$
0=f(b)-f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})=\frac{b-a}n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}}
$$
Use [The Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) (which is a corollary of Rolle's Theorem) on each interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the function $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(a+\frac{(b-a)(x+k)}{n})$, $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Eh, thanks but what am I supposed to do with that function? How did you come up with it?

Comment: @drawar: Please check that Rolle's theorem is applicable for $g$, and then apply it to $g$ to see what will happen.

Comment: Apply Rolle's Theorem in what points?

Comment: @Tomás: Rolle's theorem impies that $g_n'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(0,1)$, so for $c_k=a+\frac{(b-a)}{n}(c+k)$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f'(c_k)=0$.

Comment: i cant see this. Is $g_n(0)=g_n(1)$?

Comment: @Tomás: Yes, it follows from $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: yes you are right @Richard, i just saw it, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Tomás: Never mind.

Comment: (+1) I was just looking at the question again, and before looking at my old answer, I thought of this answer. It's very logical.